# How to ignore a character in split method

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

My file has the data in this format:

```
Name,Sal,Address,Location
Mike,"£10,732",xxxxxx,GBR
Bob,"£6,450",xxxxxxx,Fra
Arthur,"£8,320",xxxxx,Spa
James,"£7,423",xxxxxxxxxxxx,IRE
```

I need to read this data into a string array. In my new file I need to write Name,Sal and Location columns only. Here is my code:

```
    Dim ioReader As New System.IO.Streamreader("C:\old.csv")
    ioLines="Name,Sal,Location"
    Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")
    While Not ioLine = ""
        ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
        Dim values As String()
        If ioLine <> "" Then
            values = ioLine.Split(",")
            Dim outPut as string=values(0) & values(1) & values(3)
            ioLines += System.Environment.NewLine & outPut
        EndIf
```

When I am splitting the above data, the sal column values which already contains "," is splitting into 2 cells. I want to keep the sal column value as a single cell by ignoring "," in between numbers. Any suggestions please?

Comment: the source file is not well formed. Is it possible to change the source file ? To be more precise, you have to wrap the strings between `"` delimiters in order to avoid the inner `,` to be considered as a separator. You also have to update your code to handle string delimiters

Comment: That CSV is invalid. It should be escaped to `Mike,"£10,732",xxxxxx,GBR` - otherwise it is ambiguous. What if I have £10 and in the next column (unrelated) I have the value 723?

Comment: or you can also use fixed width columns, again if you can change the source file. it's eaysier to parse, because you can substring, instead of walking in the file looking for tokens

Comment: No I should not format the source file. My output file should looks like

Comment: You should understand then that this is **not** a CSV file then.

Comment: Name,Sal,Address,Location
Mike,10,732,GBR
Bob,6,450,Fra
Arthur,8,320,Spa
James,7,423,IRE    I can takeoff £ symbol using substring. But only problem is "," in the sal string values

Comment: Why can't you use a normal csv file using quoting or escaping?

Comment: If sal value is in double quotes like "10,732" , how can i escape the "," in between the numbers

Comment: The whole point is that you don't need to escape the `,` as the field is already escaped (by surrounding it with `"`).

Comment: If sal value is in double quotes "£10,732", how can i remove the £ symbol from the value?

Comment: Even though the value is like "£10.732", values(1) is appearing as "£10 and values(2) is appearing as 732".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are parsing CSV, if yes you can use

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

e.g.

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser("c:\logs\bigfile")
MyReader.TextFieldType = 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","c}
        MyReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
Dim currentRow As String()
'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    Try
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        ' Include code here to handle the row.
    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & 
        " is invalid.  Skipping")
    End Try
End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
Dim outPut as string=values(0) & values(1) & "," & values(2) & values(5)
```

The input file is not proper CSV - the fields with `,` should be escaped (surrounded with `"`):

```
Name,Sal,Address,Location
Mike,"£10,732",xxxxxx,GBR
Bob,"£6,450",xxxxxxx,Fra
Arthur,"£8,320",xxxxx,Spa
James,"£7,423",xxxxxxxxxxxx,IRE
```

And I wouldn't use `string.Split` but a CSV parser - you could use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and dirty...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private void Test(){
    Regex rex = new Regex(@"(?<!£\d*),");
    string[] s = rex.Split(@"Name,Sal,Address,Location Mike,£10,732,xxxxxx,GBR Bob,£6,450,xxxxxxx,Fra Arthur,£8,320,xxxxx,Spa James,£7,423,xxxxxxxxxxxx,IRE");
}
```

The regex will not split on comma preceeded by a pound-sign and digits. However this will only allow for one comma in the currency and so `£10,342,234` will break it...